# How can I right-align the css tabs' navigation buttons?

Tags: html, css

The link below is the live demo and the codes. How can I move the tab buttons to the right?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wbp3he8/)**

```
.tabs {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto
}
.tabs li.tab {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
.tabs .tab>label {
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.tabs .tab-content {
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top: 8px;
    min-width: 90%;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply `text-align: right` to the `ul` element.

```
.tabs > ul {
    text-align: right;
}
.tabs li.tab {
    text-align: left;   /* normalizing */
    float: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/5wbp3he8/5/)**

Comment: Thank you so much. I wish i could vote up your answer, but 14 more reputations to go for me to make a voting...

Comment: @inpyo i will vote him up :) for his quick answer :)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py yeah happening with me too. but when I add the changes directly to OP's fiddle.. everything works fine. Strange. not sure what could be the problem. :/ (_removed fiddle_)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py The issue was that I am clicking on `tidy up` button in jsfiddle which was breaking the code. updated the fiddle. :)